# Warning: More % conversions than data arguments - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7-beta2

```
-(void)updateResult {
    @try {
        if (questionFlag == INSERT_IMAGE_DETAILS) {
            [self getImageDetail];
            [m_ivwMainConsumerImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:PROFILE_PHOTO_FILEPATH,[[[DataModel sharedConsumerData] images] lastObject]]]];
        }
    }
    @catch ....
```

I am new to Objective C and the above code snippet is a part of a program where I am getting the warning: 'More % conversions than data argument' for the line

```
[m_ivwMainConsumerImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:PROFILE_PHOTO_FILEPATH,[[[DataModel sharedConsumerData] images] lastObject]]]];
```

Can you please let me know how to overcome this error?

Thanks

Comment: What is `PROFILE_PHOTO_FILEPATH`?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means that your formatting string (`PROFILE_PHOTO_FILEPATH`) has more format specifiers than parameters you are providing to it (you are only providing one, the lastObject of the DataModel's images).

For example:

if `PROFILE_PHOTO_FILEPATH` is "%@ %d" it expects some object %@ and an integer %d. So you would need to call `stringWithFormat:` this way:

[NSString stringWithFormat:PROFILE_PHOTO_FILEPATH, [[[DataModel sharedConsumerData] images] lastObject], 42];

Obviously this is just an example, without seeing the contents of PROFILE_PHOTO_FILEPATH I can't be more specific.

See this document for more details on how string format specifiers work:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Comment: '#define PROFILE_PHOTO_FILEPATH @"%@/MNE_Images/%@' is the content of PROFILE_PHOTO_FILEPATH